# How do i get audio on a website without a view/download limit?

Tags: html, audio

I'm a beginner coder and i'm currently working on a music website for my friend, he makes music. He would like to share it on his github website, but when we uploaded his audio file on to his Github respiratory, it says "Sorry about that, but we can’t show files that are this big right now.".

I found a solution by placing the audio into google drive. However google drive has a view/download limit, so after the audio has been viewed multiple times, it stops working.

I have been googling for a solution for hours, but could not find a solution. Any idea?
example code:

```
<audio controls controlsList="nodownload">
<source src="https://docs.google.com/uc? 
export=download&id=1AU1wuVJMkXWKe7oS6Hak1syLls-g0Hla">
</audio>
```

Is there a way to get rid of the google drive view limit, a way to by pass the github large file limit, or another site i could use which doesn't have a limit.

Comment: Have you/they tried using something like https://soundcloud.com/ ? They have several iframe embed options available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soundcloud and Hulkshare are dedicated to music hosting. They are way better google drive for music hosting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i will try soundcloud